# How can I debug an Actionscript project in Flex builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flexbuilder

I am trying to use Flex builder for the first time in years. I haven't used the "Run Application" option before, and when I do that now it tells me "Errors exist in required projects" and whether I should proceed. I would like to debug those errors.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

PS: When I click the "Debug" button, it does exactly the same thing. I don't see error output in the console views.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the Problems view is open (Window -> Show View -> Problems).

That will show you what compilation errors exist that need to be fixed before you can launch the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will not be able to launch the program until you fix the compile-time errors.

Open the 'Problems' pane, fix compile errors, and then the program will run.