# Does anyone else use the Flare toolkit? I need some help!

Tags: flash, flexbuilder, visualization, flare

I am trying out the fantastic Flare toolkit, but following the tutorial almost out the gate, I got stuck. I am using Flex builder and there seems to be an error in one of the included library files  (Visualization.as), and there isn't anything I can do to fix it -- I can't even debug the error, as I already wrote [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669960/how-can-i-debug-an-actionscript-project-in-flex-builder), because Flex Builder doesn't show the error messages. So that is the problem. I'd appreciate some direction and advice.

Comment: tell me your IDE type and version and include flare version too. thanks.

Comment: How do you know that there's an error specifically in Visualization.as if Flex Builder isn't showing you error messages? Have you opened the Problems pane as suggested in the answers to your other post?

Also: you're referring to Visualization.as as an included library file, which strikes me as odd. Do you mean that you have Flare itself open as a project and there's an error shown in the **source** file Visualization.as? Or do you mean that you have a project of your own open and you've added flare.swc to the build path libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this may help: but first why can't you debug ?

Anyhow I am doing as you are.  Try downloading the toolkit again and making a fresh project then follow the tutorial advice on importing flare into your project:
   1.
      In the Navigator pane, right click the top folder of the “Tutorial” project
   2.
      Click “Properties” in the context menu
   3.
      In the resulting dialog, click “ActionScript Build Path” in the left panel (it should be the 3rd item from the top)
   4.
      Click the “Library path” tab in the right panel
   5.
      Click the “Add Project” button
   6.
      You should now see a list of projects, including flare.
   7.
      Select “flare” and then click “OK”
Let me know if this helps